# onRetainNonConfigurationInstance with Multiple Threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, resume

I have about resuming multiple threads within the same Activity: I've three different threads in my app, that I call AThread, BThread and CThread.

If my app is closed and reopened, I need to reopen all preview Threads. How could I do that? I thought on returning a list of threads. Is that a good option? Something like:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return new ArrayList<Thread>(AThread, BThread, CThread);
}
```

And than, at the function onCreate, call a "for each" that verifies all Threads. Something like

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
(...)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<Thread> allThreads = (ArrayList<Thread>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        AThread = allThreads.get(0);
        BThread = allThreads.get(1);
        CThread = allThreads.get(2);
        if (AThread != null && AThread.isAlive()) {
            // TODO SOMETHING
        }
        if (BThread != null && BThread.isAlive()) {
            // TODO SOMETHING
        }
        if (CThread != null && CThread.isAlive()) {
            // TODO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

Is that correct? Any better Idea?
Cheers =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Fragment` to host your `Thread`s (or more preferably an `AsyncTask`) and call `setRetainInstance(true)` in the `Fragment`'s `onCreate` method. The `Fragment` will be retained across configuration changes and the `Fragment` (and its `Thread`s) won't be destroyed along with the `Activity`. I believe this is preferred over using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`.